# Time Based Trigger Not Firing?

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I have a time based trigger set in my project. I doesn't appear to fire and I'm not sure how to debug it any further.

I have two questions:

- How do you debug time based triggers?
- Can I have a time based trigger that calls a function in my project, that then delegates to a Google App Scripts Library I created?

Comment: Set the error notification to "immediately" and you'll receive a mail regarding the error.

Comment: You can run the code attached to the trigger independently from the trigger firing.  If the code works, then it should work when the trigger fires.  For testing, you could set the trigger to fire at some time in the near future, like 30 minutes from now.  If your trigger was working, and is no longer working, then I would delete it, and re-install it.

Comment: Adding `console.log({message: "My timed trigger function is running", inputs: arguments});` as the first line of the function will give you a persistent log entry in the project's Stackdriver Logging page.